# Rendering a minimap from large bitmap

Tags: c++, directx

I'm trying to create a minimap for my game but am having an issue.

I'm using Direct2D as the graphics API and have a ID2D1Bitmap* which contains the pixel data for the loaded area of the world.

I'd like the minimap to be around 100 x 100 pixels but the ID2D1Bitmap* contains about 3500 x 3500 of pixel data. When I try to render 3500 x 3500 pixels in a 100 x 100 pixel area, the image becomes very distorted and unpleasant.

In most cases, I thought this was solved by generating a mipmap chain but I don't see any options like this offered by Direct2D.

How can I create a clear minimap using DirectX?

Answer (score 1):

Usually minimaps are done by rendering the scene using a special, top-down camera. In your case though, the amount of scaling is extreme, so you'll lose a lot of detail one way or another. However, I suspect that your biggest issue is that the *important* fine detail is lost, like contours and edges.

I suggest you try using an image processing technique to preserve those edges. You can either find a library to do these, or if you know your way around bitmaps and multiplying pixels, they're fairly simple to implement too.

To demonstrate, I'll use [this giant picture of the world map with political boundaries](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:A_large_blank_world_map_with_oceans_marked_in_blue.svg). Here's a close-up of the British Isles and an extremely scaled-down version (using basic bilinear, similar to what DirectX would be doing) to compare the loss of fine detail:

[image: british isles detail] [image: badly scaled version]

### Resize and sharpen

One easy method is to perform gradual resizes, but also sharpen at each iteration to preserve the edge detail. In this example, I'll resize to 50% and sharpen the image repeatedly until the image is tiny. Here's the result of a few iterations of resize and sharpen:

[image: resize] [image: sharpen]

[image: resize] [image: sharpen]

And here's the final result, at about 258x128:

[image: resize and sharpen result]

### Edge detection

Another method is to use an [edge detection image filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection), thicken the edges, and combine the results with the normally-scaled image. Here's the result of one such filter:

[image: edge detection]

Combined with the result of a normal scale, I get this:

[image: edges combined]